# batch insertion returns disorder identity fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity-insert

I have (tableA) with one identity field (ID), I need to insert multiple rows at once with one insertion operation, so I use table structure as a passing parameter to my stored procedure

I need the inserted id with the order of insertion so i'm running the following query in my SP
(tableB has the same structure as tableA):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ssp_Test
(
    tableA tableAType
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tableB(field1, field2, ...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
SELECT field1, field2, ... from tableA

END
```

If I run the above procedure with 100 records it returns the newly identity field with the order it inserted to the tableB, but when I run it with 500 records all of the inserted id returns with no reasonable order why this happens?

I don't need another temp table to put it there and sort that and return, i just want to know why its happening and is there any solution without using extra temp table for sorting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

It states:
"There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the output table or table variable will correspond."

I suggest using a select after your insert to retrieve the ID's.

Comment: Is it only applies to OUTPUT result or the the actual insert operation is not reliable that first record inserted first.

Comment: The OUTPUT result, the insert should be done in the order of the select. (Try adding an order by onto your select).

Answer (score 3):

If you want something ordered you'll have to use an ORDER BY clause.  There's not value in trying to rely on a physical order (even if you think you know one exists (ie because of a clustered index)

Answer (score 0):

To populate a column with a numerical sequence use ROW_NUMBER() (or a sequence in SQL Server 2012). Don't try to rely on the IDENTITY column because its behaviour can't always be controlled.